# How to manipulate Google Map after creation?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I should warn you that I am very new to website creation and Javascript.  With that out of the way.  Because of that I have a google map widget on a website I am creating.  It has made the map creation really easy, but if I really need to I  guess I could try at coding it myself.  That aside,  I would like to add buttons on the side of the map that will go to some markers I have created.

I am having difficulties getting the map object to manipulate it after its created.  I can't seem to find what the widget calls the map object and so I just can't use the idea of making my map variable a global object.

I am just trying to change the default zoom to start with.  Below is what what I am basically trying to do but whenever the code is executed, but my map turns into a gray box on my screen.

```
<html>  
<head>
<style>
  #map {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  }
</style>
</head>  
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8">google.load("maps","2.x"); google.load("jquery","1.3.1");</script>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

  function initMap() {
    var map;
    var myOptions = {
      center: {lat: 40, lng: 50},
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      }
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, myOptions);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>

<script>
    function newLocation(newLat, newLng) {
    //var mymap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));
    var mymap = document.getElementById('map');
    mymap.setZoom(4);
    }
</script>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="myButton" VALUE="Press This" onclick="newLocation(45,88)">
<body>
</html>
```

Looking at the google developer tools I get this error
"Uncaught TypeError: mymap.setZoom is not a function."  I think this means I am getting the map area not the map itself.

Therefore is it possible to grab an instance of the map so I could manipulate it?

Comment: `map` is the map object. `mymap` is nothing but a variable that references the map DOM element. You will need to move your code to the `initMap` function or declare the `map` variable globally, so that it can be accessed inside your `newLocation` function (and of course use `map.setZoom(4)` instead of `mymap.setZoom(4)`).

Comment: Unfortunately the above is just an example of what I am trying to do with new location.  The entire creation of the map and markers is done by a widget.  And since I am new to all this I can't decipher all the spahgetti that is the page source.

Comment: https://siteorigin.com/widgets-bundle/google-maps-widget/ this is I believe what you can do with this widget. If you need more interactivity / custom behavior, why not forget about the plugin and integrate your own Google map code? I am sure you can find info on how to do that in Wordpress if you don't know how to do it...

Answer (score 2):

Your not referencing the correct `map` variable that you create in `initMap()`

What I would change is make the `map` variable global, so all of your functions including `newLocation()` can access this `map` variable.

Your implementation is using `mymap` in the `newLocation()` function, this has access to the `div` container of the map, not the actual `map object` itself, which is why you can not change properties such as `zoom`.

Try structuring it something like so, so you have the correct reference to the map variable.

```
<html>  
<head>
<style>
  #map {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  }
</style>
</head>  
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8">google.load("maps","2.x"); google.load("jquery","1.3.1");</script>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var map;

  function initMap() {
    var myOptions = {
      center: {lat: 40, lng: 50},
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, myOptions);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);

  function newLocation(newLat, newLng) {
    map.setZoom(4);
  }
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>

<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="myButton" VALUE="Press This" onclick="newLocation(45,88)">
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is good. But as he says he is "very new" to javascript, you might want to explain a bit what was not working and how you fixed it.

Comment: Alas, I know that is a solution.  However, I am not actually creating the google map, this wordpress widget is.  So I don't think I have access in changing the map variable status to global.  I actually can't find what they call it in the page source.  So that is why I was hoping to grab it some other way and just manipulate what I need in the newLocation function.

Comment: @orangestorm87 Well we can only provide guidance with the information that is given :)

Comment: I guess I am now just asking is it possible to grab the map instance after its created?  And if so, what would be some good resources for me to check out on how to do it. @BobbyW

Comment: @orangestorm87 Where did you get the code for your question when you said you cannot find the code from the Wordpress plugin?

Comment: The code in my question was my feeble attempt at coding it myself.   The widget code on my website is such a mess, I have no idea what to cut and paste to show whats going on.  So I tried to simplify my question by saying, "I have a map object which I don't believe is set as a global object, but I want to run this function on it.  How do I do it?" So its @BobbyW

Comment: Ultimately I believe you need a reference to that `map object`. I don't believe there is a way to get a reference to the map object from the `DOM` atleast not easily. I would `modify` the wordpress widget if I were you and if you don't know how to do that, I would update this question with code from the widget, so we could provide further help.

Comment: Well it is part of the siteorigin plugin bundle.  But for the life of me I can't find where it's code is located at.  I know where to edit plugins, but can't find the specific part for the google maps plugin.